# Simplest way to convert a list to a set based on a boolean property?

Tags: java, list, loops, dictionary

I have a list of Objects, each of which has a boolean "selected" property. I want these in a set if the "selected" property is true. Other than a for loop through the objects adding each to the set, is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: And you want to map from what to what?

Comment: You could get a library to do the looping and property accessing for you (Google Guava could do it), but that does not really make it any different (or much more concise to code).

Comment: You want to have a set or a map? If map, what is the value for the key?

Comment: @JigarJoshi: By "map", I think he means "set" (which he says one-out-of-three times).

Comment: Apologies, I did mean "set". Rushed that question in a bit too fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something this simple just write a loop and be done with it.

If this is a pattern you're going to implement over and over:

(untested so there may be a typo or two)

```
public interface Selector<T> {
    public boolean select(T t); }

public <T> Set<T> grep(Collection<T> coll, Selector<T> sel) {
    Set<T> result = new Set<T>;
    for (T item : coll)
        if (sel.select(T)) 
            result.add(T);
    return result;
}
```

And the invocation

```
List<SomeClasss> input = ...;
Set<SomeClass>   output = grep(
    input, 
    new Selector<SomeClass> { 
        public boolean select(SomeClass item) {
            return some-boolean-function-of-item; // decide which items to keep here
        }
    }
);
```

Implementations of `Selector` know how to examine objects and decide if they should be kept.

Comment: Note how the invocation is not less to type than the straight-forward loop... Java 8 will bring help here.

Comment: Also note how every time you need to use this code a new instance of Selector is created. Moreover, a new class is generated for every time you need this kind of iteration. Therefore - I'd really advice to use a simple `for` loop.

Comment: I've just gotta come to terms with the fact that loops are sometimes the most efficient method. Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

You can use any functional java library for it. 
For example, from my experience with Lambdaj ( http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/ ):

```
Set<Entity> entitiesSet = new HashSet<Entity>(filter(having(on(Entity.class).getSelected(), equalTo(true)), entities));
```

Answer (score 1):

Hm, I guess what you're searching for is a functional approach. I would recommend taking a look on either [lamdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/) (if you want to stick to Java and need an API only) or [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) (if you would like a richer set of features).

**An example**

The imperative version:

```
List<Sale> salesOfAFerrari = new ArrayList<Sale>();
for (Sale sale : sales) {
    if (sale.getCar().getBrand().equals("Ferrari")) 
        salesOfAFerrari.add(sale);
}
```

You can do it in one line with lambdaj:

```
List<Sale> salesOfAFerrari = select(sales,
    having(on(Sale.class).getCar().getBrand(),equalTo("Ferrari")));
```

Comment: Added a small clarification to the example (the lambdaj example was the second one).

Answer (score 1):

if you used [java 8](http://jdk8.java.net/lambda/) you could do this :

```
List<MyObject> myList = Arrays.asList(a,b,c,d);

Set<MyObject> mySet = myList
        .filter(e -> e.getMyBool())
        .into(new Set<MyObject>());
```

Assuming `a` - `d` are just instances of your object with the boolean property. But java 8 is not out yet, so I would just use a for loop.

Comment: Re; collection literals: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700775/why-collection-literals  Did this actually make the cut for 7 or 8?

Comment: @Thilo I don't think so for 7